# Converting a list of values into array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently scraping a set of values from a website using this code:

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

        for reviewtype in soup2.findAll('div', {'row_label'}):
            if 'Excellent' or 'Very Good' or 'Average' or 'Poor' or 'Terrible' in reviewtype.text:
                reviewtype.text.strip()
                reviewbar = reviewtype.findNext('span')
                reviewfill = reviewbar.findNext('span')
                reviewnum = reviewfill.findNext('span')
                reviewnumlist = reviewnum.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip().split(r'</span>')
                print np.array(reviewnumlist)
```

It pulls the data like so:

```
['254']
['30']
['5']
['5']
['2']
```

I would like it to come out like this:

```
['254'], ['30'], ['5'], ['5'], ['2']
```

But my current methods aren't working. Any insight would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty list, append relevant items and `print` it out at the end instead of printing objects individually within the `forloop`.

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

result = []
for reviewtype in soup2.findAll('div', {'row_label'}):
    if 'Excellent' or 'Very Good' or 'Average' or 'Poor' or 'Terrible' in reviewtype.text:
        reviewtype.text.strip()
        reviewbar = reviewtype.findNext('span')
        reviewfill = reviewbar.findNext('span')
        reviewnum = reviewfill.findNext('span')
        reviewnumlist = reviewnum.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip().split(r'</span>')
        result.append(revirenumlist)
print result
```